# When is it possible to interchange independent (Riemann or Lebesgue) integrals and limits?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Specifically, if we have a function of two variables $f(x,y)$, does the following identity hold?
$$\lim_{x\to c}\int_a^bf(x,y)\,dy=\int_a^b\lim_{x\to c}f(x,y)\,dy$$
Under what conditions is this true? Is it enough to say that both the integral and the limit exist for this exchange to be valid? Is this true when integrating over more general sets, not necessarily a compact 1-dimensional interval?

Answer (score 1):

The Dominated Convergence Theorem gives a partial answer:

> Let $(X,\mathfrak X,\mu)$ be a measure space, $(Y,d)$ be a metric space, and $f:X\times Y\to \mathbb C$ a function such that $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is intregrable for every $y\in Y$. Suppose that there is some integrable $g:X\to \mathbb C$ such that, for every $y\in Y$, $|f(x,y)|\le g(x)$ for almost every $x\in X$. Let $y_0\in Y$. Then
> $$
> \lim_{y\to y_0} \int_X f(x,y)d\mu(x) =\int_X f(x,y_0)d\mu(x)
> $$

To prove this, note that $y\mapsto \int_X f(x,y)d\mu (x)$ defines a function $h:Y\to\mathbb C$, and we need to study $\lim_{y\to y_0} h(y)$. This can be done with sequences.

I suppose you could relax this to $(Y,\tau)$ being a topological space with some decent countability assumptions, although I've never needed something of such generality.

---

Going a different route:

> Suppose that $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are metric space, $f:X\times Y\to \mathbb{C}$ is uniformly continuous (with respect to the metric $d_{X\times Y}((x,y),(x',y'))=d_X(x,x')+d_Y(y,y')$), and $\mu$ is some *finite* Borel measure on $X$. Suppose also that $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is integrable (on $X$) for every $y\in Y$. Let $y_0\in Y$. Then
> $$
> \lim_{y\to y_0} \int_X f(x,y)d\mu(x) =\int_X f(x,y_0)d\mu(x)
> $$

To see this, fix $\varepsilon>0$. Pick $\delta>0$ witnessing the uniform continuity of $f$. If $d_Y(y,y_0)<\delta$, then $d_{X\times Y}((x,y),(x,y_0))=d_Y(y,y_0)<\delta$, so that $|f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in X$. But then
$$
\left| \int_X f(x,y)d\mu(x)-\int_X f(x,y_0)d\mu(x)\right|\le \int_X |f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)|d\mu(x)\le \varepsilon \mu(X)
$$

A very common occurrence of this phenomenon is in PDEs, when trying to study the limit of the integral of some function on the boundary of a bounded subset of Euclidean space, say after an application of the Gauss-Green Theorem.

A less-sharp version of the previous result is when $f$ is differentiable with bounded Jacobian. Then you can use the Mean Value Theorem to bound the differences $f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)$.

Comment: Ah, I see, we had used dominated convergence like this in class to prove that one can differentiate under the sign of the Lebesgue integral, so I had guessed the limit exchange should be more or less valid as well. So, say I have a function $f$ and a point $(a,b)$ of and want to show that $\lim_{h\to0}\int_0^1\frac{f(a+h,b+th)-f(a,b+th)}{h}\,dt$ is in reality $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a,b)$, can I now take the limit inside and just use the definition of the partial derivative ($b+th$ becomes $b$ as $h\to0$) to say these two things are in fact equal?